# MouseEvent.BUTTON3 on link hitting page instead

Tags: java, selenium

So, I'm completely new to Java.  Not like the guy who just finished his first Java class, more like the guy who's learning Java off youtube so he can write a script.  I'm sure I'm not aware of best practices, so I welcome any constructive criticism.

At this point in the script, I've opened a webpage, submitted a file and it's processed.  It then takes me to another page with 4 files that have information based on the uploaded file.  I need to download those 4 files to a specific directory, one by one.  Obviously, I'm focusing on downloading the first one as the others will be retrieved using the same process.  The problem is that at this point the right click I attempt occurs one the webpage itself, and not on the link for the first file. I'm also posting all this in hopes someone will laugh at me and tell me there's some process that handles this in 2 lines.  :-)

```
    //download the first resulting file - sum
    driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("sum"));
    robot.mousePress(MouseEvent.BUTTON3_MASK);
    robot.mouseRelease(MouseEvent.BUTTON3_MASK);
    for (int counter=1; counter<=5; counter++){
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
    }
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

    //pause awhile to allow the file to be processed
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        //Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }

    //save path variable
    String saveSum = save + "\\" + year + "\\" + doy + "\\" + site + doy + ".sum";

    //pause
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    //apply the path and file
    StringSelection ssSum = new StringSelection(saveSum);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ssSum, null);

    //perform native keystrokes for CTRL+v and ENTER keys
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);    
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);            
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);          
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

The link for all this is: http://apps.gdgps.net/apps_uploads/default/da3f6d29f233a327189194ced394132a/index.html

Comment: Err... so I'm thinking this is more of a Selenium(?) question, rather than a Java question. You're going to have to supply more information, particularly the HTML that you're trying to scrape. And if I'm not mistaken, you can do something like driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("sum")).click(); rather than messing with all that Robot stuff.

Comment: Ah, there is selenium involved.  I didn't think about that.  I didn't bother with the link because unless you have the correct type of file to upload, you cant get to the page I'm actually interacting with. As for the regular click(), it then tries to save to the download folder, even after I've set the browser to prompt to save.  I need to place the files in a specific folder. I could move them to the folder they need to end up in, but I was trying to save them to the correct folder in the first place.

Comment: Is it suppose to be using the middle mouse button?

Comment: Robot's mouse2 mask is the wheel click/middle mouse click. The right button is BUTTON3 mask, so he's correct on that count.

Comment: Ok, so I tested the link and it appears that it will work without uploading files.  http://apps.gdgps.net/apps_uploads/default/da3f6d29f233a327189194ced394132a/index.html